# double fireEvent doesn't work in my react-testing-library test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm using React Testing Library and Typescript.

I need to test my menu: click on a button, test if a `Popper` with content is visible, click again on a button and test if a `Popper` with content is not visible. Also I test if triggering button is visible all the time.

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, RenderResult, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { AMenu } from './AMenu';

const firstMenuItemLabel = 'Location 1';
const menuTriggerLabel = 'locations';

describe('<AMenu />', () => {
  let component: RenderResult;
  let button: Element;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = render(
      <AMenu
        classes={{
          root: '',
          menuButton: '',
        }}
      />
    );
    button = component.getByText(menuTriggerLabel).parentElement as Element;
  });

  it('should show and hide on click on menu trigger',  () => {
    expect(button).toBeVisible();
    expect(component.queryAllByText(firstMenuItemLabel)).toHaveLength(0);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(button).toBeVisible();
    expect(component.getByText(firstMenuItemLabel)).toBeVisible();
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(component.queryAllByText(firstMenuItemLabel)).toHaveLength(0); // <- here it fails
  });
});
```

All works well in browser. The `AMenu` there are no dependencies on screen size.

When I `console.log(component.debug())` I can see rendered component with `Popper` visible after first event fireing. Second fire doesn't change component HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make use of `waitFor` and `waitForElementToBeRemoved` to be sure that you're waiting for the elements to be added/removed from the DOM before asserting on them.

See: https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-appearance